# Print non-ASCII characters into a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to create a CSV file using php. How can I print non ascii characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to use unicode characters in CSV-files, just make sure you use the right HTTP-headers. This works great in OpenOffice, but if I remember right Excel has some problems displaying CSV-files with unicode characters.

Furthermore you should try to use [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), it makes things easier. When you are creating files on the fly, you can use the [php output stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

So something like this:

```
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
fputcsv($handle, $fields, ';', '"');

fclose($handle);
```

**EDIT**
After reading your comments it seems you have problems converting htmlentities like `&eacute;`. To convert these entities you have to make sure every field is decoded. You can do this with [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) like this:

```
$decoded_string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Btw, most of the time it's not a good idea to store text with htmlentities in a database, because when you don't want to output html (like in this case) you have to convert them back to real characters. It's easier to just store the text as unicode.

Answer (score 4):

[fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) should handle utf-8.

Comment: Hi! The csv file is being generated on-the-fly and not through a file pointer. The header is sent through the header() php instruction and each record is dynamically added through echo().
Best regards!

Comment: Rui: you can still generate the file on-the-fly with fputcsv('php://output') infact, this is a much better way of creating CSV files in PHP than by concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use, I am sure it could use a little refining for your situation but overall very generic and very useful for many situations.

You just feed the function your sql and it will spit out a csv with a header line of the column names.

```
<?php
function exportMysqlToCsv($csvsql,$filename = 'export.csv')
{
    $csv_terminated = "\n";
    $csv_separator = ",";
    $csv_enclosed = '"';
    $csv_escaped = "\\";
    $sql_query = $csvsql;

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query);
    $fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);


    $schema_insert = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
    {
        $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
            stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
        $schema_insert .= $l;
        $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
    } // end for

    $out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
    $out .= $csv_terminated;

    // Format the data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = '';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
        {
            if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
            {

                if ($csv_enclosed == '')
                {
                    $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
                } else
                {
                    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $j);
                    if($meta->type == "int" || $meta->type == "real")
                    {
                      $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
                    } else {
                      $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                $schema_insert .= '';
            }

            if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
            {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
            }
        } // end for

        $out .= $schema_insert;
        $out .= $csv_terminated;
    } // end while

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
    // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    //header("Content-type: text/csv");
    //header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    echo $out;
    exit;

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, they are generated on-the-fly (i.e. you're using `echo` etc to directly output them), then following will help:

1) Add this header at very beginning of your PHP code:

```
 header ('Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
```

2) Add this meta in the HTML code:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

3) Save your PHP code file as *UTF-8 without BOM*.

Comment: Hi!
Still not working. All the non-ascii-chars are being displayed as html entities (é as &eacute;, for example).
Best regards.

Comment: surely
    header ('Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8')
is what you want if you are outputting CSV?

Answer (score 0):

When you select the page info for the web page, check what is the file encoding. Its should be UTF-8. If not, the data that you are outputting is non UTF.
Also please what Character encoding your browser has set. In Firefox its in menu->view->character encoding.

Comment: The character encoding of Firefox is set to UTF-8. The php source file is also UTF-8.

Comment: Before you echo the csv string in your php script can you do an mb_check_encoding (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php)  Try mb_check_encoding($csvString, 'UTF-8');

Comment: Also if you find that the encoding of string is not UTF-8, you can try using mb_convert_encoding (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Answer (score 0):

actually shamittomar's answer is very nice but it miss one thing

your problem is related to your encoding
you should convert your text encoding to UTF-8 
since php using  ascii internally

example :

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str , "UTF-8") ;
```

consult the php.net for more information

Answer (score 0):

The best example which I found is this one.

```
    function str_to_csv($row) {
        if ($row == '') {
            return array();
        }
        $a = array();
        $src = explode(',', $row);
        do {
            $p = array_shift($src);
            while (mb_substr_count($p, '"') % 2 != 0) {
                if (count($src) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                $p .= ',' . array_shift($src);
            }
            $match = null;
            if (preg_match('/^"(.+)"[\r\n]*$/', $p, $match)) {
                $p = $match[1];
            }
            $a[] = str_replace('""', '"', $p);
        } while (count($src) > 0);
        return $a;
    }

    function file_getcsv($f) {
        $line = fgets($f);
        while (($a = str_to_csv($line)) === false) {
            if (feof($f)) {
                return false;
            }
            $line .= "\n" . fgets($f);
        }
        return $a;
    }

    function file_to_csv($filename) {
        ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
        $a = array();
        $f = fopen($filename, 'r');
        while (!feof($f)) {
            $rec = file_getcsv($f);
            if ($rec === false) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!empty($rec)) {
                $a[] = $rec;
            }
        }
        fclose($f);
        return $a;
    }

    $data = file_to_csv('base2.csv');

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use `utf8_encode()` function, where you want to print or get non ASCII Character.